# Create treemap like chart in python

Tags: python, visualization, hierarchical-data, treemap

I have a data frame that I would like to use to create a Treemap like chart, similar to the one in the attached image. Below is the code to generate the data followed by a code that I have tried but the treemap didn't give the desired results.

Code to generate data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9','C10', 'C11', 'C12','C13', 'C14'],
        'A': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 
        'B':[3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        'Cat': ['UP','UP','GONE','GONE','GONE','GONE','GONE','GONE','UP','UP','GONE','MID','MID','MID']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print (df)
```

The above creates the underlying data and the below will create the counts - the aggregated version of the above data. The logic behind this aggregation is:

```
If A = 2 & B = 2 then Cat = MID ... 
If A = 2 & B = 1 then Cat = GONE ... 
If A = 1 & B = 1 then Cat = GONE ... 
If A = 1 & B = 2 then Cat = GONE ... 
If A = 2 OR A = 1 & B = 3 then Cat = UP
```

Based on the underlying data, this will result in
4 cases for UP,
3 cases for MID and
7 cases for GONE.

```
data_agg = {'Cat': ['UP', 'GONE', 'MID'],
        'Count': [4, 7, 3] 
        }

df_agg = pd.DataFrame(data_agg)

print (df_agg)
```

I have tried using squarify to create the chart I want but it doesn't give the desired results. The squarify code I used is below:

```
colors=['red','green','blue']
squarify.plot(df_agg['Count'], label=df_agg['Cat'], color=colors, alpha=0.5)

squarify.plot(df_agg['Count'], label=df_agg['Cat'], color=colors, alpha=0.5)
```

I need to create a chart like the last picture and any help in creating that will be greatly appreciated.
The current result I get is
[image]

The desired chart result is this, with the variables A and B showing on the Axis:
[image]

Comment: If you need the number of groups, I think this idea is rejected, but if you set the y-axis and x-axis as columns A and B, you can draw the following graph, which I'll expand into [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PRTcsW2Bkno9RpJmHBRFnXEYsGa_SKL3?usp=sharing) if that's okay.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose squarify is not the right tool for what you want, as it only allows comparing quantities by size in a fixed space (here df_agg['Count']).

Comment: Thanks, Yeah you're right but I couldn't find anything else that would be similar to the chart I want.